# How do I prove that 2 vector spaces are equal if they have different number of vectors that span them?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For example, in 4-dimensions, vector space V is spanned by the linearly independent vectors x, y, and z
and vector space U is spanned by the linearly independent vectors r, and s. Would I try to prove that the vectors x, y, and z can span U and vectors r, and s can span V?

Comment: Depends whether they are linearly independent. For example if the spanning vectors of $V$ are linearly independent it is impossible for two vectors to span $V$.

Comment: That's one way! If the vectors are given e.g. "numerically" in $\Bbb{R}^4$ (or with respect to a known basis of the 4D space), then you can also do the following. Form a 3x4 matrix with rows x,y,z. Calculate the reduced row echelon form. Do the same with the 2x4 matrix with rows r and s. The spanned subspaces are equal if and only if the non-zero rows of the two RREF-matrices are equal.

Comment: @JonasLenz oh, my bad I forgot to mention that they are linearly independent, ill edit that in

Comment: In that case, $\dim V=3\ne 2=\dim U$, hence $V\ne U$

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ and $S'$ are subsets of a vector space $V$, then $\operatorname{span}(S)=\operatorname{span}(S')$ if and only if each vector of $S$ is a linear combination of elements of $S'$ and vice-versa.

Consider, for instance, the case in which:

- $V=\mathbb{R}^3$;
- $S=\bigl\{(1,-1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)\bigr\}$;
- $S'=\bigl\{(2,-1,-1),(-1,-1,2)\bigr\}$.

I claim that $\operatorname{span}(S)=\operatorname{span}(S')$. In order to prove it, all I have to do is to note that:

- $\displaystyle(1,-1,0)=\frac23(2,-1,-1)+\frac13(-1,-1,2)$;
- $\displaystyle(1,0,-1)=\frac13(2,-1,-1)-\frac13(-1,-1,2)$;
- $\displaystyle(0,1,-1)=-\frac13(2,-1,-1)-\frac23(-1,-1,2)$;
- $\displaystyle(2,-1,-1)=(1,-1,0)+(1,0,-1)$;
- $\displaystyle(-1,-1,2)=-(1,0,-1)-(0,1,-1)$.